# Inserting word beside another word starting from the end of list

Tags: scheme, racket

I have code which is inserting new word on the right side of choosen word

```
(define insertR
  (lambda (new old lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) (lst))
      (else (cond
              ((eq? (car lst) old)
               (cons old
                     (cons new (cdr lst))))
              (else (cons (car lst)
                          (insertR new old
                                   (cdr lst)))))))))
```

i need to make it insert that word beside first appearance of word starting from the end of list. Tried to work with reverse but could not get that to work.

Comment: What is `lat` in `(null? lat)`? Why nesting the `cond` rather than adding terms in the same?

Comment: sorry it should be (null? lst) edited

Comment: Now it should work. Doesn't it? How do you use it and what do you expect the outcome should be?

Comment: its working its adding the word to the first appearance in list e.g. `(insertR dog cat (horse cat snake cat turtle)` > `(horse cat dog snake cat turtle)` but i want it to add the word to the last appearance  like `(horse cat snake cat dog turtle)` idk how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two strategies you can take to add it next to the last occurence.

The first is to use a helper and start off with the reverse list. This is very simple and my preferred solution.

```
(define (insert-by-last-match insert find lst)
  (let loop ((lst (reverse lst)) (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst) 
        acc
        (let ((a (car lst)))
          (if (equal? a find)
              (append (reverse (cdr lst))
                      (list* find insert acc))
              (loop (cdr lst) (cons a acc)))))))
```

The other one is kind of obscure. Whenever you find the element you replace `last-match` with a callback that replaces the computation since it was made and until it gets called with the replacement and the rest of the list, which of course is the correct result. The work done until the end of the list is simply discarded since it is not used, but we do it since we are not sure if we are going to find a later one and then all the work uptil that is of course included in the result.

```
(define (insert-by-last-match insert find lst)
  (define (helper lst last-match)
    (if (null? lst) 
        (last-match)        
        (let* ((a (car lst)) (d (cdr lst)))
          (cons a
                (if (equal? a find)
                    (let/cc k
                      (helper d (lambda () (k (cons insert d)))))
                    (helper d last-match))))))

  (helper lst (lambda () lst)))
```

`call/cc` (or its variant `let/cc`) is often described as time travel or advanced goto. It is not very intuitive. Here is a CPS version:

```
(define (insert-by-last-match insert find lst)
  (define (helper lst last-match k)
    (if (null? lst) 
        (last-match)        
        (let* ((a (car lst)) (d (cdr lst)) (k2 (lambda (v) (k (cons a v)))))
          (if (equal? a find)
              (helper d (lambda () (k2 (cons insert d))) k2)
              (helper d last-match k2)))))
  (helper lst (lambda () lst) (lambda (v) v)))
```

Basically this is the same as the previous only that here I have written the CPS code and with the `let/cc` version the implementation does it for me and I get to use `k` exactly where I need it. In this version you see there is no magic or time travel but the execution that should happen later is simply replaced at a point.

Answer (score 0):

Write in a similar way `insertL` and apply it to the reversed list.
And reverse the result. Then you will have an insertion beside first appearance of word starting from the end of list

```
(define insertL
  (lambda (new old lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((eq? (car lst) old) (cons new lst))
          (else (cons (car lst) (insertL new old (cdr lst)))))))

(define last-insertR
  (lambda (new old lst)
    (let* ((rlst (reverse lst))
           (result (insertL new old rlst)))
      (reverse result))))
```

test:

```
(last-insertR 'aa 'a '(b c d a h i a g))
;; '(b c d a h i a aa g)
```

By the way, the beauty of `cond` is that you can put the conditions always at the beginning - listed one under the other.
So one can write your `insertR` nicer as:

```
(define insertR
  (lambda (new old lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((eq? (car lst) old) (cons old (cons new (cdr lst))))
          (else (cons (car lst) (insertR new old (cdr lst)))))))
```